# Link one key to two tables conditionally

Tags: mysql, sql, reference, foreign-keys

I have three tables `Table1 (Name, Roll), B( ID, School) & C (ID, State)`

`Roll in Table 1` is the Foreign Key

How do I reference `Table1(Roll)` to `B(ID)` or `C(ID)`?

Condition is that if `Roll > 500`, reference should be to `B` and if `Roll <= 500`, It should reference to `C`

What is a generic way to create multiple references if we are allowed to modify `Table1`? Viz. Link Table1 of any table (A, B, .. , X, Y, ...) depending on the condition. 
Is it even possible in SQL?

Added Edit: I dont need to JOIN it, I just need to REFERENCE it.

Comment: you can't. A particular FK is to one and only one table. You can implement complex *composite foreign keys* however

Comment: @Drew: How does one implement composite foreign keys?

Comment: I think I wrote up 2 or 3 of the four seen in this search [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+foreign-keys+composite) ... and I tagged them as such. Perhaps they can be useful. They can certainly cure insomnia.

Comment: There is also the concept of mysql *conditional joins* ... they are implemented with left joins

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

if you are using t-sql/ pl-sql, the best method is to create functions and/or conditions that allow you to flow to use the proper table to reference. please elaborate more on what you would like to accomplish and on what you are working with.

Comment: I'm working with Mysql. I need to accomplish multiple references from Table 1 to B, C. Reference should be from Table1 to B if Roll > 500 & to C is Roll <=500